# reflect the changes without having to redeploy the app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, web-deployment

Even if I need to modify a single line in one of the web-page , I have to redeploy the whole project from to GAE from netbeans. This as seems is not good. Several *application context* variables that I use in the website *(I store some light data in the application context variables through my cpanel)* are lost. Is there any way I can make changes on some web pages without having to redeploy the whole project ? I am using google appengine as my application server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend you look at JRebel. I have not personally used it though have looked into using it. It does exactly what you are talking about.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

Answer (score 2):

you can use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) for that. An example (with Eclipse, though) [here](http://androidisland.blogspot.com/2010/09/appengine-jrebel-and-eclipse-getting.html)

Comment: It works fine with any IDE. If fact, JRebel was implemented IDE-agnostic from the beginning. However, IDE plugins help when debugging as debugger gets confused if you add new method and try to set a breakpoint to the new code.